# .NET XML Node Self Closing Tag

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have a piece of XML which contains a Self Closing Tag like follows:

```
    <GivenNode />
    <GivenNode>This has some data in it</GivenNode>
```

How do I test if "GivenNode" is empty?

```
    If Not objChildNOde.SelectSingleNode("GivenNOde").Value Is Nothing Then
                        'Do Something or other
    End If
```

This returns false either way, I know it must be pretty easy but I just cant figure it out. I would rather not have to change either the code I am using at the moment of the XMLFile but I can if I have to.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can verify if it has children.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has the same problem as me I got around it by using the following code

```
     If Not objChildNOde.SelectSingleNode("GivenNode").InnerText = String.Empty Then
                        //Do Something or other
      End If
```